# Does json-rule-engine maintain fact state at engine level

Tags: json-rules-engine

We have java application which sends multiple concurrent requests to NodeJs application to evaluate different rules, which is backed up by json-rule-engine. Currently, we are using single instance of engine() to evaluate rules.

So, Question is, should be creating new engine instance per API call or single instance would be safe to handle the multiple concurrent API call [i.e Engine is not retaining data level state between multiple calls]